# Sort numbers and NaN conditionally

Tags: javascript, arrays

I try to sort example array:

```
const array = [5, 9, NaN, 3, 15];
```

My expected result is:

```
const expected = [3, 5, 9, 15, NaN];
```

So the numbers are sorted ascending and the `NaN` values are at the end.

I tried with simple

```
const res = array.sort((a, b) => a - b);
```

or

```
const res = array.sort((a, b) => {
   if (a > b) return 1;
   if (b > a) return -1;
   return 0;
});
```

But none work. Side question - why the result is the same in both cases?

```js
const array = [5, 9, NaN, 3, 15];

const res1 = array.sort((a, b) => a - b);
const res2 = array.sort((a, b) => b - a);

console.log(res1, res2);
```

Comment: The result is the same because `.sort()` sorts **in place**. The array is returned for convenience.

Comment: What are the results of your attempts? Or at least embed the examples as Snippets so they can be run easily.

Comment: Only the fact that `res1` and `res2` are arrays is constant. After the code is run, they both point  to the same `array`  which the `sort()` method has mutated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the delta of the `NaN` value, too.

For getting an independent array take a new array with spreaded values.

```js
const
    array = [5, 9, NaN, 3, 15],
    res1 = [...array].sort((a, b) => isNaN(a) - isNaN(b) || a - b),
    res2 = [...array].sort((a, b) => isNaN(a) - isNaN(b) || b - a);

console.log(...res1)
console.log(...res2);
```